# Facebook Share dialog just refreshes page

Tags: javascript, facebook, mobile, sdk, share

I have used the below code to implement the Facebook sharing dialog.  VERY occasionally, it pops open a share dialog.  97% of the time, it just refreshes the page.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<a href="someurl.com/some-article" data-image="myimage.jpg" data-title="My Article Title" data-desc="My description" class="btnShare">Share</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
        FB.init({
            appId: 'myappID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
    };
    (function(d, debug){var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if(d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id;
        js.async = true;js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);}(document, /*debug*/ false));
    function postToFeed(title, desc, url, image){
        var obj = {method: 'feed',link: url, picture: 'http://www.url.com/images/'+image,name: title,description: desc};
        function callback(response){}
        FB.ui(obj, callback);
    }


    $('.btnShare').click(function(){
        elem = $(this);
        postToFeed(elem.data('title'), elem.data('desc'), elem.prop('href'), elem.data('image'));

        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Most likely a JavaScript error occurs in your `postToFeed` function, and therefor the `return false` does not get executed, and then the default action of the link is executed, which is to go to the location in the `href` attribute. Use jQuery’s [event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) instead of the return statement, and do it before you call your `postToFeed` function. Then, when “nothing happens”, go check your browser’s error console.

Comment: Thanks CBroe. Appreciate your help.